# DrawText in canvas (SkiaSharp) : Text does not display

Tags: xamarin.forms, skiasharp

My problem is:  text does not display on canvas

```
SKPaint _paint = new SKPaint();
using(Stream stream = _assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(fontPath))
{
_paint.Typeface = SKTypeface.FromStream(stream);
}

canvas.DrawText ("12345",X,Y,_paint);
```

If I don't use "using block" or "dispose", it works like a charm.

But if I do, before it reaches canvas.DrawText, _paint does not null but all values in FontMetrics, FontSpacing or TextSize equal 0.

Then there is no text on canvas.

I'm so confused, could you give me some advice, please ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is happening is that you are disposing the stream and then trying to use it. `SKTypeface` takes ownership of the stream and you must not close it yourself. Ass soon as the typeface is no longer in use, it may decide to close the stream.

The correct way to use this is to open the stream, pass it to `SKTypeface` and then just worry about the typeface:

```cs
SKPaint _paint = new SKPaint();
Stream stream = _assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(fontPath);
_paint.Typeface = SKTypeface.FromStream(stream);

canvas.DrawText ("12345", X, Y,_paint);
```

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/SkiaSharp.SKTypeface.FromStream/p/System.IO.Stream/System.Int32/

> Returns a new typeface given a stream. Ownership of the stream is transferred, so the caller must not reference it again.

Comment: Thanks for your comment ^^ Really thankful ^^

- But if I want to release unmanaged resource (that stream), anyway  I could try? 

- Because close the stream inside Draw() is quite expensive as this method is called many times.

// I tried put it in destructor, but it went so weird, destructor was called 2-3 times BEFORE the text appearred (at least it appearred)

// (It's not just for this problem, I really like fixing memory leak, give me some advise, please)